# Git LFS with files on Artifactory and pointers on Github

Tags: github, artifactory, git-lfs

I want to set up Git LFS using Artifactory as storage, but I also want the pointer files to be present on my Github repository.

It's been working fine when I had Github as storage for Git LFS - but from what I understand my Github remote and Git LFS storage were separate repositories, so I don't really get why Git shows me this error when I try to push:

```
remote: error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 2 unknown Git LFS objects
```

Is what I want impossible to get or did I make some mistake during set-up?

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously uploaded LFS files to GitHub, then GitHub will check to see whether you've pushed all your LFS files and reject the push if not.  If you want to store your LFS files elsewhere, then you need to write into GitHub Support and ask them to delete your LFS files stored on GitHub.

As long as you have any LFS files on GitHub for this repository network, GitHub will do this check.

Comment: So i should ask Github support to delete just the whole files from Github storage-repository, or also pointer files from my main Github repo?

Comment: No, you should keep the pointer files.  Just write into GitHub Support, explain the situation and show them the error message, and ask them to remove the LFS files they're storing.  Be absolutely sure you've pushed them all to Artifactory first.  They'll know what to do.